# Moving mysql datadir not working? Problems with symlink in conf.d?

Tags: mysql, directory

I wanted to have my mysql config in svn to be versionised so i did thefollowing:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-226-50-211:~/mysql-config$ ls -la /etc/mysql/conf.d/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-01-27 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2011-01-27 11:42 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 2011-01-27 11:45 flimmit.cnf -> /home/ubuntu/mysql-config/flimmit.cnf
```

A link in conf.d folder points to my local config.
The global mysql config is untouched, i installed a fresh release of ubuntu lucid LTS.

flimmit.cnf looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address           = 0.0.0.0
max_connections        = 600
server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db            = flimmit_shop_14
binlog_do_db            = flimmit_search_14
datadir         = /media/mysql-ebs/datadir
```

The chmod of this config is 644

So i stopped mysql, activated the config, moved all contents of /var/lib/mysql to the new location /media/mysql-ebs/datadir

same for the log, but there wasnt any yet.

i chowned the whole /media/mysql-ebs folder to mysql.mysql (recursively)

the contents of the data dir are

```
debian-5.1.flag  ibdata1  ib_logfile0  ib_logfile1  mysql  mysql_upgrade_info
```

problem is now that the `sudo start mysql` seems to hang

my mysql error.log states:

```
110127 11:57:58 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

Some place i read something about not copying `ib_arch_log_0000000000, ib_logfile0`.

So what files to copy? What not? And Why?

Ps:

I tried it also with moving only the mysql folder (mysql database) and nothing else. same thing. I also read something about modifying the init script, but theres no such thing in my init script and i would really find it stupid if the datadir would have to be defined in the init script and the config file.

Pps:

after a while i saw that apparmor was running, so i adjusted the rules accordingly:

```
  #/var/lib/mysql/ r,
  #/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/ r,
  /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/** rwk,
```

for now i discarded the changement of the log dir and focused only on the data dir. but somehow this didnt change anything. of course i restarted apparmor.

Ppps:

i confirmed the problem IS appaormor. after running `/etc/init.d/apparmor teardown` everything worked fine. But what is wrong with the config? I will post it as a whole:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Tue Jun 19 17:37:30 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>
  #include <abstractions/mysql>
  #include <abstractions/winbind>

  capability dac_override,
  capability sys_resource,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,

  network tcp,

  /etc/hosts.allow r,
  /etc/hosts.deny r,

  /etc/mysql/*.pem r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/ r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/* r,
  /etc/mysql/my.cnf r,
  /usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
  /usr/share/mysql/** r,
  /var/log/mysql.log rw,
  /var/log/mysql.err rw,
  #/var/lib/mysql/ r,
  #/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/ r,
  /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/** rwk,

  /var/log/mysql/ r,
  /var/log/mysql/* rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,

  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally forgot to add the external config file to apparmor profile.
now everything works

Comment: How does one do this?

Comment: app armor got installed as default with the ubuntu server upgrade to version 10.04 which i was not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that mysql user has access to /home/ubuntu/ directory?

Comment: yes, i became mysql using sudo -u mysql bash -l and was able to cat the content of the config file

Answer (score 1):

Try change permission to datadir:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /media/mysql-ebs/datadir/
chown mysql:mysql /media/mysql-ebs/
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i chowned recursively